# How to find a name containing "space" in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a BD.txt file with the following content:

```html
Person1:Boston:20
Person2:New York:18
Person3:New York:25
Person4:New Orleans:30
```

I have to show how many people live in New York. I used:

```html
cat BD.txt | grep New York | wc -l
```

The output was "3" instead of 2. "New York" has a space char on its name, and it finds only "new" (counting some results I don't want, like "New Orleans").

What should I use to find words containing sapce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotation marks around `New York`:

```
cat BD.txt | grep "New York" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

if I read the question correctly then it states to find the files having space in their name so below command will work

to find files in current directory only

```
find .  -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*' '\* -prune
```

to find files in all subdirectories also

```
find . -type f -name \*' '\*
```